# Multiple inheritance for an anonymous class

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, anonymous-class

How can an anonymous class implement two (or more) interfaces? Alternatively, how can it **both** extend a class **and** implement an interface?
For example, I want to create an object of anonymous class that extends two interfaces:

```java
    // Java 10 "var" is used since I don't know how to specify its type
    var lazilyInitializedFileNameSupplier = (new Supplier<String> implements AutoCloseable)() {
        private String generatedFileName;
        @Override
        public String get() { // Generate file only once
            if (generatedFileName == null) {
              generatedFileName = generateFile();
            }
            return generatedFileName;
        }
        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception { // Clean up
            if (generatedFileName != null) {
              // Delete the file if it was generated
              generatedFileName = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

Then I can use it in a try-with-resources block as `AutoCloseable` as lazily-initialized utility class:

```java
        try (lazilyInitializedFileNameSupplier) {
            // Some complex logic that might or might not 
            // invoke the code that creates the file
            if (checkIfNeedToProcessFile()) {
                doSomething(lazilyInitializedFileNameSupplier.get());
            }
            if (checkIfStillNeedFile()) {
                doSomethingElse(lazilyInitializedFileNameSupplier.get());
            }
        } 
        // By now we are sure that even if the file was generated, it doesn't exist anymore
```

I don't want to create an inner class because I'm absolutely sure that this class won't be used anywhere except the method I need to use it in (and I also *might* want to use local variables declared in that method that might be of `var` type).

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to make the constructor visible in places that otherwise it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Anonymous classes *must* extend or implement something, like any other Java class, even if it's just `java.lang.Object`.

For example:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   public void run() { ... }
};
```

Here, `r` is an object of an anonymous class which implements `Runnable`.

An anonymous class can extend another class using the same syntax:

```
SomeClass x = new SomeClass() {
   ...
};
```

What you can't do is implement more than one interface. You need a named class to do that. Neither an anonymous inner class, nor a named class, however, can extend more than one class.

Comment: I don't think the second expression is correct. You've already declared the name of the class as SomeClass, it's not anonymous anymore. Check out this link http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm When you "new" an interface, an anonymous class is created by extending "Object" class and implementing that interface. But while you are "newing" a class with the first expression you wrote, an anonymous class (In fact, it's an instance of that anonymous class is created) will be create by extending that class.

Comment: @youmiss: The 2nd expression will create an instance of an anonymous class which extends `SomeClass`. It is still anonymous, due to the `{...}`.

Comment: I see, I overlooked the {...}.

Answer (score 37):

An anonymous class usually implements an interface:

```
new Runnable() { // implements Runnable!
   public void run() {}
}

JFrame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() { // extends  class
} );
```

If you mean whether you can implement *2* or more interfaces, than I think that's not possible. You can then make a private interface which combines the two. Though I cannot easily imagine why you would want an anonymous class to have that:

```
 public class MyClass {
   private interface MyInterface extends Runnable, WindowListener { 
   }

   Runnable r = new MyInterface() {
    // your anonymous class which implements 2 interaces
   }

 }
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's google friendly for people looking for implementing 2 or more interfaces in anon implementation.

Answer (score 29):

I guess nobody understood the question. I guess what this guy wanted was something like this:

```
return new (class implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void myInterfaceMethod() { /*do something*/ }
});
```

because this would allow things like multiple interface implementations:

```
return new (class implements MyInterface, AnotherInterface {
    @Override
    public void myInterfaceMethod() { /*do something*/ }

    @Override
    public void anotherInterfaceMethod() { /*do something*/ }
});
```

this would be really nice indeed; but **that's not allowed in Java**.

What you **can** do is use [local classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) inside method blocks:

```
public AnotherInterface createAnotherInterface() {
    class LocalClass implements MyInterface, AnotherInterface {
        @Override
        public void myInterfaceMethod() { /*do something*/ }

        @Override
        public void anotherInterfaceMethod() { /*do something*/ }
    }
    return new LocalClass();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what the OP intended IMHO

Comment: givng a thumbs for answering the asked question. which is normal on SO that people like to answer what should be asked not what has been asked.

Answer (score 16):

Anonymous classes **always** extend superclass or implements interfaces. for example:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // ActionListener is an interface
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    }
});
```

Moreover, although anonymous class cannot implement multiple interfaces, you can create an interface that extends other interface and let your anonymous class to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

```
// The interface
interface Blah {
    void something();
}

...

// Something that expects an object implementing that interface
void chewOnIt(Blah b) {
    b.something();
}

...

// Let's provide an object of an anonymous class
chewOnIt(
    new Blah() {
        @Override
        void something() { System.out.println("Anonymous something!"); }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous class is extending or implementing while creating its object
For example :

```
Interface in = new InterFace()
{

..............

}
```

Here anonymous class is implementing Interface.

```
Class cl = new Class(){

.................

}
```

here anonymous Class is extending a abstract Class.

Comment: I don't see the difference. How yours is different then mine.

Comment: a nice and compact one, what I miss in you answer is word like "always" or "must" :)