# Interface Vs anonymous class in android

Tags: android

I am little bit confused regarding backend working of anonymous class, like if we have a button and we are setting onclickListener

```
Button B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
B.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){ 
          public void onClick(View V){ 
              Log.v("","Hello world");
          }
 ));
```

What is here actually happening in backend ?Does this will implement interface of View.OnClickListener or something else???

Comment: Please look over this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848510/how-can-an-anonymous-class-to-extends-or-implements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous classes must always extend a class or implement an interface.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View V) { 
        Log.v("", "Hello world");
    }
});
```

In this case, you are creating a new anonymous (unnamed) class that implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface. This works because the `setOnClickListener` method takes an argument of type `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: There is simple typo here that could be confusing.  There is no onClickListener Interface.  It is OnClickListener.

Answer (score 2):

Please look over this

[How can an anonymous class use "extends" or "implements"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848510/how-can-an-anonymous-class-to-extends-or-implements)

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is an instance of new unnamed class that implements the OnClickListener interface.