# Undersanding animation function in android

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I want to use the following code snippet, please help me in understanding the given functions or suggest me online documentation that can I use.

```
view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            list.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            view.setAlpha(1);
          }
      });
```

what does function `setDuration(2000)` , `.alpha(0)` ,`.alpha(1)` and .`withEndAction()`

Answer (score 2):

- `setDuration(2000)` sets the duration of the animation to 2000 milliseconds or 2 seconds
- `alpha(0)` the view's alpha property will be animated to this value
- `withEndAction()` means at the end of the animation the following action will take place

Have a look here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html)

Comment: can you please tell more about Runnable() and why its name is capitalized b'coz most of methods in java begins with small letter. @Ken Wolf

Comment: @NikhilBalyan Runnable is an Interface (so it's capitalised) and we are implementing it, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5848516/833647

Answer (score 0):

check this post, you can understand better

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: can you please elaborate Runnable() why it is used and its purpose.