# Why an anonymous class can't implement two separated interfaces but can implement inner interfaces?

Tags: java, anonymous

An anonymous class can extend only from one class or interface, so I can't do the next :

```
interface Enjoyable {
    public void enjoy();
}

interface Exercisable {
    public void exercise();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Enjoyable implements Exercisable() {
            public void enjoy() {
                System.out.println(":D");
            }
        }.enjoy();

    }
}
```

It says that :

> Enjoyable.Exercisable cannot be resolved to a type

I'm trying to replicate this behavior and I wrote the next code:

```
interface Enjoyable {
    interface Exercisable {
        public void exercise();
    }
    public void enjoy();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Enjoyable.Exercisable() {
            public void enjoy() {
                System.out.println(":D");
            }

            public void exercise() {
                System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

            }
        }.exercise();

        new Enjoyable.Exercisable() {
            public void enjoy() {
                System.out.println(":D");
            }

            public void exercise() {
                System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

            }
        }.enjoy();

    }
}
```

And then I get :

> Doing exercise !!! :D

Are there another way to simulate It? 
And way i hace to implement both metods un the anonymous class ?

Thanks

Comment: In your second snippet, your anonymous class is implementing `Exercisable`, not `Enjoyable`.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want an anonymous class who implementa 2 interfaces methods

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an anonymous class use "extends" or "implements"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848510/how-can-an-anonymous-class-use-extends-or-implements)

Comment: This isa different question i want to replicate implement two interfaces un the anonymous type not only one

Comment: add `@Override` and you'll see the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Exercisable's are not Enjoyable :-)
nesting interfaces this way does not mean that the inner interface is
of the type of the outer interface !

you could just as well have written something like

```
new Object() {
            public void enjoy() {
                System.out.println(":D");
            }

            public void exercise() {
                System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

            }
        }.enjoy()
// same for .excercise()
```

so you are not actually simulating an anonymous class that implements two interfaces.

you can see this when you actually try to assign your anonymous instance to a variable of a type of your interfaces

```
// this WILL NOT COMPILE !
Enjoyable enjoyable=new Enjoyable.Exercisable() {
            public void enjoy() {
                System.out.println(":D");
            }

            public void exercise() {
                System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

            }
        }.enjoy();
```

you could of course do something like this :

```
interface Enjoyable {
    public void enjoy();
}

interface Exercisable extends Enjoyable {
   public void exercise();
}
```

and then create anonymous instances using those interfaces
Unfortunately creating an anonymous instance that implements two interfaces  like you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: But why you must implements both method s un the anonymous type?

Comment: @ Alejandro Agapito Bautista .. sorry i'm not quite sure how to understand your comment ... i implemented both methods in the examples because i just adopted your code ... of course in the first example implementing 'excercise' is superfluous

Answer (score 3):

> I want an anonymous class who implements 2 interfaces methods

I assume you mean you want an anonymous class which implements two interfaces. You can't, directly.

You can do

```
interface EnjoyableAndExercisable extends Enjoyable, Exercisable {
}
```

and then create an anonymous class that implements that.

```
EnjoyableAndExercisable o = new EnjoyableAndExercisable() {
    @Override
    public void enjoy() {
        System.out.println(":D");
    }
    @Override
    public void exercise() {
        System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

    }
};
```

Note the `@Override` which will always validate whether you are actually overriding a method or not.

In your code however, this anonymous class

```
new Enjoyable.Exercisable() {
    public void enjoy() {
        System.out.println(":D");
    }

    public void exercise() {
        System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

    }
}.enjoy();
```

is only an implementation of `Exercisable`. You just happen to declare a method with the name `enjoy` within it.

You cannot assign it to a variable of type `Enjoyable`

```
Enjoyable ref = new Enjoyable.Exercisable() {
    public void enjoy() {
        System.out.println(":D");
    }

    public void exercise() {
        System.out.println("Doing exercise !!!");

    }
}; // nope, compile time error
```

You can only invoke that method on the new instance creation expression that declares this anonymous type. You cannot invoke it any other way (since it's declared in an anonymous type).

Answer (score 0):

You can create anonymous inner classes based on a non-final class or an interface with

```
new Exerciseable(){
...
}
```

However, Java does not allow

```
new Object() implements Exercisable{
...
}
```

or

```
new Object implements Exercisable(){
...
}
```

The anonymous inner class produces with the `new` keyword a new instance of a class whose superclass is `Object` and implements `Exercisable`. The JCP site hosts a document (https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/JLS/innerclasses.pdf), belonging to the JSL about inner classes which says:

> As already hinted, if an anonymous class is derived from an interface
>   I, the actual superclass is Object, and the class implements I rather
>   than extending it. (Explicit implements clauses are illegal.) This is
>   the only way an interface name can legally follow the keyword new. In
>   such cases, the argument list must always be null, to match the
>   constructor of the actual superclass, Object.

Your second example constructs a type `Exercisable` which extends `Enjoyable`. Creating anonymous classes of that interface is legal again.